# Spring boot application error constructor Order in class Order cannot be applied

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a spring boot sample application. The code just builds up an order list. But, I am getting the following error when i build on IntelliJ. The error looks, there is no constructor on Order (java) class, but I didn't find how to fix this kind of error.

OrderDao.java:

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import com.example.demo.domain.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Repository
public class OrderDao {
    public List<Order> buildOrders(){
        return Stream.of(
                new Order(101, "Mobile", 20.0, 1),
            new Order(102, "Book", 9.1, 2),
            new Order(278, "Book", 1.2, 3),
            new Order(953, "Jeans", 12.3, 1)
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Order.java:

```
package com.example.demo.domain;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Order {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

}
```

Error when building in IntelliJ:

```
error: constructor Order in class Order cannot be applied to given types;
            new Order(101, "Mobile", 20.0, 1),
            ^
```

required: no arguments
found:    int,String,double,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: `int,String,int,int` where's the `double`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem comes from lombok configurations:
For correctly configuring lombok on your spring boot app, you need few things

1. Need to enable annotations processor inside intellij. Go to settings->build,
   execution, deployment-> Compiler -> Annotation processor: Verify that Enable
   annotation processor checkbox is turn on.
2. Just add lombok dependency in pom.xml, with provided scope and without
   version because in spring boot parent pom it is exists with correct version.

If this two step will not work, you can try this:
[maven compiler plugin-> annotation processor path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfxjR.png)

Comment: Hi Razmik, I did the first point. Secondly, i am using gradle, not pom.xml. My build.gradle has implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'

Comment: For gradle you can try this one:

dependencies {
 compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
 annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
}

Comment: dependencies {
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
 implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.2'
 implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:3.11.1'
 implementation 'com.amazonaws.serverless:aws-serverless-java-container-spring:1.5.2'
}

Comment: I have the above in build.gradle. but still this error is coming up

Comment: Can to check Order.class under target folder ?
Their take a look that lombok generates the constructors

Comment: Ok, just by control + click lombok.AllArgsConstructor; right? yes, it's opening

Comment: If their not exists constructor, you should add the compileOnly and annotationProcessor in gradle file, and after that you should build the project with gradle: 
https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Comment: No, with that approach you can see the AllArgsConstructor annotation implementation under the lombok. When you are running project javac compiles your .java files to .class files. In your example for Order.java file should be generated Order.class file. Lombok is injecting the Getter Setter AllArgsConstructor etc. in your Order.class (if lombok is working).